# Game Timer Using Pygame

Tags: python, timer, pygame

I am working on a reaction game using Pygame and have run into a few difficulties with the timer. Currently how this code functions, is that when you start the program, you have to hit "a" for the countdown timer to start. As the letter appears on the screen you hit the corresponding keyboard key, which updates the score. The two things I would like to change have to do with the timer. I would like for the timer to autostart without having to hit the "a" button and I would like for the score to not continue to tally once the time has expired.

You will see some of my previous attempts commented out. In all of the versions where I have tried to implement the auto timer, the timer rapidly ticks off, rather than waiting a second in between counting off.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import os, sys
import random
import time

time_a = 20
a_on = False
n1 = time.time()
letter = ["c", "b"]

pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Reaction Game")

background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
rect = background.fill((0, 0, 0))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
score = 0
font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 36)
scoreupdate = font.render(format(score), 1, (255, 255, 255))
x = (random.choice(letter))
xupdate = font.render(format(x), 1, (255, 255, 255))
print x

#mainloop
while True:
  clock.tick(30)
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
      sys.exit()


    if event.type == USEREVENT:
      if time_a > 0:
        time_a -= 1
      else:
        break
      #else:
        #pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT, 0)

    elif event.type == KEYDOWN:

      if event.key == K_a:
        if not a_on:
          # Set for 1 second (1000 milliseconds)
          pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT, 1000)
          a_on = True
        else:
          # The other one should turn on immediately
          pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT, 0)
          pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT+1, 1000)


      if x == "b" and event.key == K_b:
        n3 = time.time()-n1
        print n3
        score += 1
        n1 = time.time()
        scoreupdate = font.render(format(score), 1, (255, 255, 255))
        print "B button Hit" 
        print score
        x = (random.choice(letter))
        xupdate = font.render(format(x), 1, (255, 255, 255))
        print x

      if x == "c" and event.key == K_c:
        n3 = time.time()-n1
        print n3
        score += 1
        scoreupdate = font.render(format(score), 1, (255, 255, 255))
        n1 = time.time()
        print "C button Hit" 
        print score
        x = (random.choice(letter))
        xupdate = font.render(format(x), 1, (255, 255, 255))
        print x                      


      if event.key == K_PAUSE or event.key == K_p:
        #pause both timers
        pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT+1, 0)
        pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT, 0)

      #pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT, 1000)
      #a_on = True

  # Format time into minutes:seconds
  #pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT, 1000)

  time_a_str = "%d:%02d" % (int(time_a/60),int(time_a%60))

  time_a_txt = font.render(time_a_str, 1, (255, 255, 255))
  score_txt = scoreupdate
  letter_txt = xupdate

  letter_rect = letter_txt.get_rect()
  letter_rect.center = (160, 30)
  score_rect = score_txt.get_rect()
  score_rect.center = (30, 30)
  time_a_rect = time_a_txt.get_rect()
  time_a_rect.center = (310, 310)

  screen.blit(background, rect)
  screen.blit(xupdate, letter_rect)
  screen.blit(scoreupdate, score_rect)
  screen.blit(time_a_txt, time_a_rect)
  pygame.display.update()
#end mainloop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at [this example of a timer](http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/f.php?file=timer.py). It should have what you need.

Comment: I had to take the frame rate down to make the time accurate. I also added a conditional statement for the time being greater than zero to make sure that the score didn't update once it was finished.